# How do I get everytime 10 distinct random rows out of 500 rows with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created below table and this table has 500 raws.

```
CREATE TABLE Education_question
(
  EducationId int IDENTITY(101,1),      
  EductionText Varchar(MAX)
);
```

we are implemented paging in this case. Out of 500 raw we have fetch only 10 raw in single Store procedure call. second time i called same Store procedure it will give next 10 raw. And most important thing is that i have to fetch that 10 raw randomly out of remaining raw.
I fired below query then i get 10 row but some raws are repeated(get raw which are get previously) in that data. how i get distinct 10 raws.

```
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM Education_question
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Use `select top (10) distinct * from ...` to return rows that have different column values

Comment: How can you get duplicate rows??? You query the table just once and each record has a unique id. So every record you select with your statement is unique. Or are you talking of repeated executions of your query, where you expect it to give you other random records everytime you run it and never show a row that a former execution showed?

Comment: i am implemented paging in this case. Out of 500 raw we have fetch only 10 raw in single Store procedure call. second time i called same Store procedure it will give next 10 raw. And most important thing is that i have to fetch that 10 raw randomly out of remaining raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) * FROM chirag_Education_question ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: here i don't have redundant data. i have 500 raw data and i get only 10 raw every time. so i fired same query 50 time then i get whole 500 raw data. Reason for doing that i have huge amount of data in single raw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script to get the result you need:

```
DECLARE @idx int
DECLARE @TotalRows int
DECLARE @NewNumber int
DECLARE @RowNumbers TABLE(RowNum int)

SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(*) FROM Education_question
SET @idx = 0

WHILE(@idx < 10)
BEGIN
    SELECT @NewNumber = RAND() * 10000
    WHILE(@NewNumber > @TotalRows)
    BEGIN
        SET @NewNumber = @NewNumber/10
    END
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @RowNumbers WHERE RowNum = @NewNumber)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RowNumbers(RowNum) VALUES(@NewNumber)
        SET @idx = @idx + 1
    END
END
SELECT EducationId, EductionText FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EducationId) AS 
        RowId, * FROM Education_question) OrderedRecords 
WHERE RowId IN (SELECT RowNum FROM @RowNumbers)
```